# How to get Data from getAll() method inside an Activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Database structure:

**Detail** table

```
 rid     name
  1      Beta
  2      Release
```

**Record** table

```
 recid     rname   conrid (conrid is rid from Detail table)
   1       App1      1
   2       App2      1
   3       App3      2
   4       App4      1
```

I have written a method to get all the data from both the tables (Detail and Record) based on `rid` and `conrid`.
Here is the code:

```
String select = "SELECT rname FROM " + TABLE_RECORD+ " where conrid =" +detail.getId();
```

Comment: try `select Details.name,Record.rname from Detail INNER JOIN Record ON Record .conrid=Detail.rid`

Comment: Note that you should not do this in main thread. Also such methods IMHO should be in a separate class. You should separate GUI from your business logic. So having this method in your Activity is already not a good idea. Also those method names... Use more detailed names, it will make your code much more readable.

Comment: @Sophie I cannot help you resolve your issue while my eyes are bleeding. Good luck with it.

Comment: What data do you want?

Comment: I don't know why @MD deleted his answer, because it's correct (undelete that!). How to retrieve the data? The very same way you would with a "non JOIN" query.

Comment: Simply skip the first query. Replace the second one with the "JOIN" query @MD provided (hopefully, undelete your answer!). DONE. More about SQLite JOINs: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm

Comment: @MD Yes, but... A good answer is still a good answer. Not worth deleting it. Or is it?

Comment: @Sophie. How would you read from a single table? A JOIN query returns a cursor filled like if it was a single table. Once you run the query, just use the cursor. THAT'S ALL - Nothing more than that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94091/discussion-between-sophie-and-frank-n-stein).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are closed in a loop where you're byting your tail...
So, I'll mix together your code with the answer provided by @MD.

I'm confident he doesn't take it bad. ;)

You will need to add a Class named `RecDet` (containing the Name field from Detail and RName from Record).

Use that one in place of `Detail` and `Record`.

```
// to get all data from Detail and Record tables
public List<RecDet> getAll()
{
    List<RecDet> listRecDet = new ArrayList<RecDet>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery =
        "SELECT Details.name, Record.rname FROM Detail INNER JOIN Record " +
        "ON Record.conrid = Detail.rid";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            RecDet recdet = new RecDet();
            recdet.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
            recdet.setRname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("rname")));
            listRecDet.add(recdet);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return listRecDet;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, today i got how to work with multiple joins in SQLite... that was too easy really !

Comment: Multiple JOINS will help you joining more than 2 tables. "Typical" use: Joining 3 tables in a `Many-To-Many` relation. Yes, it was easy. Now you should deepen your knowledge over RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this

```
select Details.name,Record.rname from Detail INNER JOIN Record ON Record.conrid=Detail.rid
```

Comment: @Sophie This is `SQL` command you have to execute it with `Cursor`

Comment: @Sophie. Once you run the query, you get a Cursor. Like if your queried a single table. Just use the Cursor. DONE!

Comment: @Sophie Please, do some effort. We can't feed you with the spoon!

Comment: @Sophie This behaviour is called "The Help Vampire". If you know how to extract data from a table to a cursor, this is really THE SAME.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein This is the reason `why i deleted my answer.` I want to help but not time to give all the code..